# different routing for every components using ngSwitchCase

Tags: angular, typescript

Is possible to have different routing for every components?
I have this situation:
one main component with one panel for select some voice.
inside the main component I have one container switch, when the user select the panel the nested component are showed, but the routerLink remain always the same.
I would like to have for example :

```
mainrouterlink_with_the_id_of_item/labeling
```

or

```
mainrouterlink_with_the_id_of_item/activity
```

or

```
mainrouterlink_with_the_id_of_item/settings
```

if is possible how can do that?

```
<div class="mt-0">

                        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="selectedPanel">
                            <!-- Labeling -->
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'labeling'">
                                <dashboards-recipe-label></dashboards-recipe-label>
                            </ng-container>
                            <!-- Activity -->
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'activity'">
                                <dashboards-recipe-activity></dashboards-recipe-activity>
                            </ng-container>           
                            <!-- settings -->
                            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'settings'">
                                <dashboards-recipe-settings></dashboards-recipe-settings>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible. To give a more precise answer we would need more context. If you could provide a more detailed information about why you want to do that and the code that goes with this flow we could help you with better answers.

With the information we have you would need to map those routes to the same component in your routing module and navigate to the route when necessary.

But if your component has only this, maybe it would be better to have three separate components and navigate using the route.

```
...
   {
       path: 'labeling',
       component: YourComponent,
   },
   {
       path: 'activity',
       component: YourComponent,
   },
   {
       path: 'settings',
       component: YourComponent,
   },
...
```

If it is only your route that defines what should be displayed, you should change the whole ngSwitch block for the  tag.

```
<div class="mt-0">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And use navigation to change the route instead of using a variable.

```
goToSettings() {
  this.router.navigate(['mainrouterlink_with_the_id_of_item/settings']);
}
```

Comment: I edit my question , I have one main component with 3 nested component selectable by the ngSwitch

Comment: @AndyBand, if the only variable that defines what component should be displayed is "selectedPanel" and it is the same as the relative path of the route were the component should be displayed, you should consider the answer given by user3929590. 

Changing the structure of your main component from an ngSwitch to a router-outlet tag since it will only displayed the component that matches the route in your routing component. 

Check [the angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) for more information about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done.

in Routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'settings', component: DashboardsRecipeSetting

  },
  { path: 'activity', component: DashboardsRecipeActivity},
  { path: 'labelling', component: DashboardsRecipeLabelling}
];
```

and in your component, instead of having the entire ng-container, just replace with below

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And from where you are selecting this, just use a routerlink

```
 <a
      routerLinkActive="active-link"
      routerLink="/settings"
     
    >Settings</a>
 <a
      routerLinkActive="active-link"
      routerLink="/labelling"
     
    >Labelling</a>
 <a
      routerLinkActive="active-link"
      routerLink="/activities"
     
    >Activities</a>
```

Comment: I edit my question , I have one main component with 3 nested component selectable by the ngSwitch